# Writing shorts greater than 127 to a ByteBuffer in Java

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

I have an application in which I'm trying to send UDP messages using TSLv5. The protocol is somewhat complicated, but to do it I need to write 16 bit values as little-endian and then send that via UDP.

Here's my code doing just that:

```java
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        buffer.putShort(SCREEN_POS, screen);
        buffer.putShort(INDEX_POS, index);

        ByteBuffer text = ByteBuffer.wrap(value.getBytes());
        short textLength = (short) value.getBytes().length;
        buffer.putShort(LENGTH_POS, textLength);

        ByteBuffer combined = ByteBufferUtils.concat(buffer, text);

        short control = 0x00;
        control |= rhTally << 0;
        control |= textTally << 2;
        control |= lhTally << 4;
        control |= brightness << 6;

        combined.putShort(CONTROL_POS, control);

        short msgLength = (short) (combined.array().length - 2);
        combined.putShort(PBC_POS, msgLength);

        return new DatagramPacket(combined.array(), combined.array().length, ip, 9000);
```

This mostly works, but the problem is when I have values that are greater than 127.

For example, my index is `148` and when all is said and done, my control comes out to be `193`. When I write those values to the ByteBuffer they become `-108` and `-63`, respectively.

I know why this happens, a ByteBuffer is an array of bytes and bytes can't be greater than 127. What I don't know is how I can achieve this? The protocol does not work if I send signed values, it has to be the exact number.

Comment: **Everything is alright.** Signed bytes are just a numerical interpretation of the bits. (byte)-63 == (byte)193. So your short or even unsigned short remain undisturbed. For instance the short 511 is {(byte)-1, (byte)1} = 255+1*256.

Comment: I'm sending this as a DatagramPacket, so that packet has the value -63 instead of 193. You're saying that on the other end they are going to know this is 193 and not -63? I'm not sure if that's true because I have the same code working in Javascript using nodejs Buffer Class. That allows me to write 193, 148, etc. That works when I make the request, but my Java code does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assure that a signed java byte will be read correctly in the two bytes of a short. I have simplified the code, writing the fields one after the other in linear fashion, with message fields in front. Also just used one ByteBuffer.

(Maybe there is some small error like a wrong offset.)

Also I send the text bytes as being in UTF-8. You used the implicit platform encoding, which may differ on every computer.

```
    byte[] text = value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int textLength = text.length;

    int length = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + textLength;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(length)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

    short control = 0x00;
    control |= rhTally << 0;
    control |= textTally << 2;
    control |= lhTally << 4;
    control |= brightness << 6;
    buffer.putShort(/*CONTROL_POS,*/ control);

    short msgLength = (short) (length - 2);
    buffer.putShort(/*PBC_POS,*/ msgLength);

    buffer.putShort(/*SCREEN_POS,*/ screen);
    buffer.putShort(/*INDEX_POS,*/ index);
    buffer.putShort(/*LENGTH_POS,*/ (short)textLength);
    buffer.put(text, 0, textLength);

    return new DatagramPacket(buffer.array(), length, ip, 9000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this and the explanation above. Turns out I did have something small incorrect - the port. Would have never realized that if I weren't reading your code line for line.